# Cannot assign "0.0": "Item.discount" must be a "Discount" instance

Tags: django, forms, foreign-keys

I know there are a ton of similar questions on here, but this is different, as it looks like it is a bug.

Model:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    serial = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    prod = ForeignKey(Product, verbose_name='Product')
    account = ForeignKey(Account, verbose_name='Account')
    pdate = DateField(null=True, verbose_name='Date') # Paid date, for imported licenses only
    price = DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, default=0)
    discount = FloatField(default=0.0)
    vat = ForeignKey(Vat, null=True) # Null is for imported licenses
    disabled = BooleanField(default=False) # To activate/deactivate license

class Discount(BaseModel):
    ID = AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = CharField(max_length=32)
    rate = FloatField(verbose_name='Rate (%)', help_text=get_help('discount__rate'))
    disabled = BooleanField(default=False)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s, %s%'%(self.name, self.rate)
```

Form:

```
class InvAddProdForm(ModelForm):
    qty = IntegerField(initial=1)
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ('prod','account','discount','vat')
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(InvAddProdForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['prod'].empty_label = None
        self.fields['prod'].queryset = Product.objects.filter(disabled=False).order_by('name')
        self.fields['account'].empty_label = None
        self.fields['vat'].empty_label = 'AUTO'
        self.fields['vat'].required = False
        self.fields['vat'].queryset = Vat.objects.filter(disabled=False).order_by('name')
```

As you can see, a class Discount exists, but Item never uses it, and still, when i try to create an instance of InvAddProdForm I get the exception

```
ValueError at /invoice/10000/
Cannot assign "0.0": "Item.discount" must be a "Discount" instance.
```

Can anyone make sense of this? I find it very peculiar. If the discount field in Item was a ForeignKey field, it would make sense to me, but it is not.! It is a FloatField

Comment: To add to this: The database table has has the discount column as a 'double' field, so the database seems to be correct

Comment: Also, it used to work, and now it doesn't after wiping an recreating the database

Comment: I think the problem is that you have a discount fload filed and a related set of Discount objects. try change the name of the distance floatfield to something else, and see if it works

Comment: I had considered that, but I don't understand how it worked before then. I'll give it a go, though

Comment: What does your BaseModel model look like?

Comment: Just some datefields and other flags... Nothing that contains the word discount. BaseModel inherits from models.Model, whereas Item inherits from BaseModel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This

`discount = FloatField(default=0.0)`

should be

`discount = ForeignKey(Discount)`

**Update**

Ok so what has probably happened is that your models.py is out of sync with what your database schema looks like. Presumably, you have changed it from a foreign key to a float field. So you need to change this in the db as well. There are 2 ways you can do this:

1. Drop the table and run syncdb again
2. Use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/)

P.S You should probably store `discount` as a Decimal Field

Comment: I get that this is what Django thinks should happen, but I want it to simply be a float field, as it has nothing to do with the discount class

Comment: The update to your answer had some truth to it. It has worked before with nothing changed but the inheritance. South was used to migrate this change, but for some reason, it screwed it up. I changed the name of the floatfield to 'disc' instead of 'discount' and migrated again, which has resolved the problem. I think south has an issue with it's naming convention when it comes to class inheritance